# How quickly does the iPad respond to touches?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios

I'm talking, how much time can be expected to elapse between the user touching the screen and something like touchesBegan being called? (Or something lower level, if such a thing is available.) Sub-millisecond? Multiple milliseconds? Tens?

Comment: Are you asking just out of general curiosity or because you are doing some calculation that could cause a delay?

If you are asking out of general curiosity, then it's fast enough that it really shouldn't matter to us as developers. That particular metric is a detail Apple needs to sweat over, not us.

If you are asking because of a calculation, then I would say that if you're asking what the limits are of doing something, then you need to seriously re-evaluate your approach. (Moved to comments per suggestion)

Comment: @Philip I think you may have misunderstood my question. I'm wondering if there's a known delay between when the user first touches the screen and the first moment my code becomes notified of this event, e.g. touchesBegan is called. I'm not asking for the upper bound of a calculation that would (somehow?) take place between when the touch occurs and when I actually hear about it. I'm wondering more how feasibly I could, say, measure a person's reaction time.

Comment: I would think that hard data on the reaction speed of the iPad from touch to display result would be difficult to come by without heading into the lower-level APIs (if that data is even accessible at all; I can see Apple wanting to keep it a secret). I've seen this question posted in game dev forums elsewhere and all I've ever seen done is user-touch to user-touch, not user-touch to screen-display.

Comment: Remember- it's going to be *slower* on an UIScrollView - to accomodate for the timer to see if it's a scroll touch

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure touchesBegan is called very quickly (meaning, with whatever minimal delay exists in the event path).  I've noticed in my code that I get a single touchesBegan for a two-fingered touch with both touches already in the list.  I assume that I don't touch both fingers down together very precisely but from what I've seen the touchesBegan event is delivered within a few milliseconds.  I suspect Apple holds the touches very briefly before passing them along in order to batch them for more efficient handling, possibly also using that delay to filter out accidental touches (sort of like de-bouncing a mechanical switch).

I use a touchesBegan in my view to freeze my scrolling animations and my perception is that the scrolling stops immediately when I touch the screen.

The real delays come from the gesture recognizers.  They often have to wait to see if you've moved far enough to signify a pan or if you've held long enough to be holding or if you've released without dragging to signify a tap.  Those delays can be substantial of course, though they're still only a fraction of a second in my experience.

Comment: +1, the perception might as well be immediate because it's faster than the 16.666~ms (1/60th of a second) or however long of a delay is on the drawing loop.